# Проигрывание видео с заданного места в ios 9

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Пытаюсь сделать так, чтобы видео начинало проигрываться с заданного места

```
[player setCurrentPlaybackTime:from];
[player setInitialPlaybackTime:from];
[player setEndPlaybackTime:to];

[player prepareToPlay];
[player play];
```

но видео все равно проигрывается с самого начала. Как заставить его играть с заданной точки?
Использую Xcode 7, запускаю на iOS 9 и iOS 8.4, результат одинаковый.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- MPMoviePlayerController очень сильно сломан, и чинить его Эпл не будет, поскольу он deprected. Я бы вам порекомендовал переходить на AVPlayerViewController.
- Нужные вам методы начинают работать только после того как воспроизведение началось.

Что надо сделать:

подписаться на нотификейшн

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
               selector:@selector(fastForward) 
               name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification 
               object:nil];
```

выполнить действие

```
- (void)fastForward
{
    if(self.player.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStatePlaying) {
        self.player.currentPlaybackTime = someTime;
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает. А как в таком случае остановить видео в нужной точке? Присваивание self.player.endPlaybackTime не работает.

Comment: не берусь сказать точно, но похоже после iOS8 `initialPlaybackTime` и`endPlaybackTime` перестали работать совсем.

Comment: Подскажите, правильно ли я понимаю, что, переходя на `AVPlayer`, мне придется использовать также и `AVPlayerViewController`, поскольку у `AVPlayer`'a нет `view`, и ему нельзя сделать `setFrame:`? К тому же, он еще и невидим - звук из видео есть, а видео не показывает.

Comment: не совсем так. AVPlayer сам по себе view не имеет, но имеет лэйер, который можно вытащить и показать на экране `AVPlayerLayer *layer = [AVPlayeLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:self.avPlayer];` для `AVPlayerViewController` вам надо создать плеер, отдать его в контроллер `playerController.player = player;` и дальше работать с ним как и с любым другим ViewController

Comment: Если не трудно, подскажите, пожалуйста, еще одну вещь. Как остановить видео в нужной точке с помощью `MPMoviePlayerController`? Может быть, тоже с помощью нотификейшнов?

Comment: @mgv я бы предложил создать таймер, который будет каждые 0.1 секунды проверять позицию воспроизведения, и остановит когда нужная точка достигнута.